# baggage field in spring sleuth is not available in MDC if custom header is inserted in request extending filter and not passed in request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a baggage field in Spring Sleuth set as
spring.sleuth.baggage.correlation-fields: correlation-id
spring.sleuth.baggage.remote-fields: correlation-id in application.yml

It's working when the correlation-id is passed as header in the request,
in some scenarios the header(correlation-id) is missing in incoming requests, and my custom filter injects the field when it's missing. In that case the field is not appearing in the MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context), I also tried setting up the Baggage field manually in the filter itself but correlation id is not passed to MDC.

i think there is an issue with the interaction between my custom filter and Sleuth's MDC integration.

i'm using spring boot version : 2.7.0
spring-cloud-started-sleuth: 3.1.1

any help would be appreciated.

i tried adding baggage field manually in the filter, setting up the filter with highest precedence, so header can be added before spring sleuth filter do it's work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.